# Ruby 2.1 and mislav-will_paginate 2.3.10 shows ERROR: NoMethodError: undefined method `paginate'

Tags: ruby, rubygems, will-paginate

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here, I installed Ruby 2.1, Sequel-4.26.0 gem and mislav-will_paginate-2.3.10 gem, but when i try to use the paginate function, i keep getting the following error:

**Code:**

@user = User.paginate(:page => 1, :per_page => 2)

**Error message:**

"ERROR: NoMethodError: undefined method `paginate' for #"

Comment: so that is the code for your controller, what does the code in your view look like? also, have you debugged to see what the value of user is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely `paginate` is a dataset method, not a class method (this is true for Sequel's pagination extension, not sure about will_paginate). If you want `User.paginate` to work:

```
def User.paginate(*args)
  dataset.paginate(*args)
end
```